# Arctis 5 Headset, Two Audio Playback devices not visible

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

This headset I'm using has two audio playback outputs, a game is assigned to one of them and a VOIP software to the other. That way you can balance between the two with a chatmix dial.

On Windows these two playback devices are visible.
[Windows playback devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xJm.png)

As shown here (Bottom Two)

However on Ubuntu 16.10 only 1 playback device is visible.
[Ubuntu playback devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlFTC.png)
This is PulseAudio

Here is some commands I ran (Maybe they will be helpful)

```
ultimate55@ultimate255-Twist:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: S5 [SteelSeries Arctis 5], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: S5 [SteelSeries Arctis 5], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Any way to get the second output device to show on Ubuntu, and hopefully  get this chat mix working?
Edit: I forgot to mention that this headset is connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio does not detect the second stereo output, and defaults to outputting audio to the chat output device.

I've created a pulseaudio profile which enables the game output as well, put it [on my github](https://github.com/DemonTPx/steelseries-arctis-5-pulseaudio-profile) and even [created a deb file](https://github.com/DemonTPx/steelseries-arctis-5-pulseaudio-profile/releases) so you can install it easily.